# Is it possible to create a flat terrain in Java Monkey Engine?

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine

As a beginner using the JME engine, I was wondering whether it is possible to create flat terrain?

I have played with the TerrainBlock and created a somewhat bumpy terrain using MidPointHeightMap, but can't seem to get it perfectly flat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a primitive plane, using a `Quad` shape.

http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/doc/com/jme/scene/shape/Quad.html

This is always perfectly flat. You can use other techniques for texturing. Also note: the Z-height of this `Quad` is always 0. (It's really flat!)